# 8tb usb drive randomly unmounts

Tags: linux, debian, usb-drive

I added a 8tb usb drive to my `fstab` using the `uuid` of the drive:

```
UUID=ab38b866-2c81-4a4e-9ff6-79b00049c83c /mnt/ext_backup_8tb ext4 defaults,errors=remount-ro,auto,user,exec,rw
```

But it keeps unmounting it randomly. Sometimes it takes a couple of minutes sometimes it takes half an hour. I'm even able to backup some data to it with rsync before it unmounts by itself.

Error from rsync when the drive randomly unmounts:

```
rsync: write failed on "/mnt/ext_backup_8tb/3d_pro/09/ra/c8/g0/ca002.tga": Read-only file system (30)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(393) [receiver=3.1.1]
```

I formated the drive GPT with gparted with an 7.42tb ext4 partition.

if I dmesg | tail I get this:

```
[33336259.049794] sd 70:0:0:0: [sdi] 4096-byte physical blocks
[33336259.050054] sd 70:0:0:0: [sdi] Write Protect is off
[33336259.050058] sd 70:0:0:0: [sdi] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[33336259.050374] sd 70:0:0:0: [sdi] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[33336259.050810] sd 70:0:0:0: [sdi] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[33336259.313038]  sdi: sdi1
[33336259.313646] sd 70:0:0:0: [sdi] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[33336259.314294] sd 70:0:0:0: [sdi] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: That message per se is harmless. So while I don't have an answer for your question (why is the drive unmounting suddenly and randomly), I think you should look a bit deeper into the system logs for the cause of this.

Comment: Are there any messages printed when the drive is unmounted? The ones you show are when it is mounted.

Comment: No messages, just the errors of rsync trying to access to an unmounted drive. What logs should I check?. syslog, dmesg, messages?

Comment: 8TB is rather large. Might it just be a power supply issue or can you exclude hardware issues?

Comment: Sadly the same harddisk formatted as NTFS works plugged on an windows machine getting the same data through the network.

Comment: `dmesg|tail` is too short output. You need longer history — including the moments the device is attached, mounted and then un-/remounted.

Comment: I added the full listing of the dmesg command as a file attachment.